# How to make mutate work with reactive on numerical column names?

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, tibble

I don't really know to hook up mutate with reactive when dealing with names of columns that are numerical.

I've got data that looks something like this:

```r
df <- tibble(a=c("a", "b", "c"), `1990`=c(1,2,3), `2010`=c(3,2,1))
```

Everything looks fine when I do:

```r
p <- df %>%
  mutate(newvar = `1990`)
```

But I want to use it in my Shiny App such that `newvar` is assigned to the input from select list.

I created this reactive for that;

```r
  selectedyear <- reactive({
    input$select
  })
```

But now it doesn't seem to work:

```r
p <- df %>%
  mutate(newvar = selectedyear())
```

I tried different modifications, like:

```r
p <- df %>%
  mutate(newvar = `selectedyear()`)
```

but nothing seems to work for me.

The full code of the app:

```r
library(shiny)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a=c("a", "b", "c"), `1990`=c(1,2,3), `2010`=c(3,2,1))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("select", "Select:", c(1990, 2010)),
  tableOutput("val")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  selectedyear <- reactive({
    input$select
  })
  output$val <- renderTable({
    p <- df %>%
      mutate(temperature = selectedyear())
    p
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The same thing, but with characters as input is easy. Do you know some hack around this?

Comment: hey, could you provide a minimal code to run the shiny app ? ;)

Comment: @bretauv Sure! Just added to the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
  output$val <- renderTable({
    p <- df %>%
      mutate(temperature = !!selectedyear())
    p
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the non-syntactic name of the columns `1990`, `2010`. The approach below should work. It uses `eval`/`parse` inside the right hand side of the `mutate` call. Note that you usually do not need to create `reactive`s of (and with only) inputs, because each input is already reactive.

```
library(shiny)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a=c("a", "b", "c"), `1990`=c(1,2,3), `2010`=c(3,2,1))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("select", "Select:", c(1990, 2010)),
  tableOutput("val")
)
server <- function(input, output) {


  output$val <- renderTable({

       df %>%
          mutate(temperature = eval(parse(text = paste0("`", input$select,"`"))))

  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you are only interested in the temperature column and you do not need to show the rest of the data, then `dplyr::select` lets you access the `input$select` variable in a much more straightforward fashion:

```
  output$val <- renderTable({

    df %>% 
      select(temperature = input$select)

  })
```